# Get Amount like Balance-Sheet in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

---

I have following data in one table...

```
Name               CourseFee   AdditionalCharges  ExpenseAmount 
Course-A           500         10                 0
Course-B           250         0                  0
Paid To Trainer    0           0                  250
```

I want following output with sql query

```
Name               CourseFee   AdditionalCharges  ExpenseAmount NetAmount
Course-A           500         10                 0             510
Course-B           250         0                  0             760
Paid To Trainer    0           0                  250           510
```

NetAmount  = (Course Fee + Additional Charges - ExpenseAmount)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want a cumulative sum of the fields:

```
select t.*,
       (select sum(t2.CourseFee + t2.AdditionalCharges - t2.ExpenseAmount)
        from onetable t2
        where t2.id <= t.id
       ) as NetAmount
from onetable t;
```

Notes:

- This assumes you have a column of some sort that defines the ordering of the rows.  It is called `id` in the query above, but it could be an id, date, or something else.  SQL table represent *unordered* sets, so such a column is necessary.
- You can do this using `outer apply` instead of a correlated subquery.
- SQL Server 2012+ directly supports cumulative sums.